# SQL, PHP update query error

Tags: php, mysql

I have some PHP code and I'm trying to insert or to update data in a MySQL table.

The insert query works, but the update query doesn't. The values are printed correctly at the end.

```
<?php
  $nm=$_GET["nm"];
  $reg=$_GET["regno"];
  $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","admin");
  mysql_select_db("Q14",$con);


  // $res=mysql_query("insert into stdtable values('$nm','$reg')",$con);

  $res=mysql_query("UPDATE stdtable SET `NAME`='$nm',`REG NO`='$reg' WHERE 
  'REG NO'='$reg'",$con);

  echo "SUCCESS";

  echo $nm.$reg;
?>
```

Comment: `$res=mysql_query("UPDATE stdtable SET NAME='$nm',REG NO='$reg' WHERE 
REG NO='$reg'",$con);` don't use back tick for column table...

Comment: @EkoJunaidiSalam backticks for column names is OK.

Comment: Do not longer use deprecated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`with prepared statement.

Comment: That update query makes no sense at all... Your query is basically saying Update every row in stdtable where the REG NO is equal to the variable $reg to REG NO= $reg. So you're changing a column to the same variable as what the where clause is saying. You're basically not changing the REG NO column.

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
'REG NO'='$reg'",$con);
```

you've used ', but has to be `

Answer (score 1):

For `REG NO` (in where clause) you have to use backticks not single quotes. Or better rename the column, without blanks in the name:

```
$res=mysql_query("UPDATE stdtable SET `NAME`='$nm',`REG NO`='$reg' WHERE 
`REG NO`='$reg'",$con);
```

Do not longer use deprecated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`with prepared statement.